# How to run my own full node pool? (error: unexpected identifier)

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, nodes, mining-pools

When I run this `geth` with the following parameters:

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "my ip" --rpcport 8545
```

I get an error like:

```
(anonymous): Line 1:13 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you maybe give the full error log and the full command line you are running? Else this will be tough to figure out what's the actual problem.

Comment: That is all :) ...............

Comment: when i type geth --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --gasprice 10000000000 -- identity "some name" 2>>geth.log the same (anonymous): Line 1:8 Unexpected identifier (and 3 more errors) plz help  ps i use geth version 1.5.0 [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iJfgl.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iJfgl.jpg)

Comment: i get an error geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost or ip -- rpcport 8545 console the error messege is (anonymous): Line 1:8 Unexpected identifier (and 3 more errors) [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YASls.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YASls.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a screen print or all the messages. Have your run just `geth` or have you run both `geth` and `ethminer`? Do you have a proxy trying to connect to `geth`? Because the proxy will send different commands from what `ethminer` sends.

Comment: and this command with my ip is the same problem

Comment: Do you have your `ethminer` or your proxy pointed to your `geth` server? Do you have any other `geth` instances running? Can you run a `killall geth` to kill any other `geth` processes. What happens then. Also can you run the command `geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 --verbosity 6 console`. What happens? The run the command `geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 9999 --verbosity 6 console`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39289/discussion-on-answer-by-coreytaylor211-how-to-run-an-own-pool-full-node-error).

Comment: @coreytaylor211 please use the [edit](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/3575/edit) button to update your issue. Don't post answers!

Answer (score 2):

## Summary

@coreytaylor211 is trying to run a remote server with a `geth` instance, and connect to this `geth` instance from `ethminer`s running from home.

The error message is generated from the following code:

```
./Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/robertkrimen/otto/parser/error.go: return self.error(self.idx, "Unexpected identifier")
```

within one of the go-ethereum code dependencies. This code is a parser for JavaScript.

I suspect that there is an application (most likely his `ethminer`s trying to connect to his `geth` instance via a proxy previously pointed to a mining pool, but now pointed to his new remote server `geth` instance).

Changing the default RPC port from 8545 to something else and connecting his `ethminer` to this new port seems to have the problem.

---

## Details

In this answer, I'll provide you with the steps to set up a `geth` instance, whether on your external server or internally in your home network. We will use the standard communication between `geth` and your `ethminer`s and if your `geth` instance is on an external server, your mining performance will not be optimal. I can help you to improve the performance but this will require additional software to be setup but get the basic `geth` and `ethminer`s running first and then we can take the next step.

In this answer, I'll assume that your `geth` instance is running on a server with the IP 123.456.1.2 .

## `geth`

On your `geth` server, run `geth` with the following parameters:

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr 123.456.1.2 --rpcport 8545 console
```

If you get errors, please post the whole error message and the commands you use in a separate answer. (We can clean up this post afterwards).

## `ethminer`

On your `ethminer` server, you should be able to connect `ethminer` with your `geth` instance using the following command (remember NO proxy to be used in this step):

```
ethminer -F http://123.456.1.2:8545
```

Again, if you get errors, please post the whole error message and the commands you use in a separate answer.

Please tell me whether this setup works. We can then take the next step.